# Adobe RGB monitor outside photoshop

Tags: windows, monitors, adobe-rgb, wide-gamut

I have a new monitor (DELL UP2716D) and can operate it in the Adobe RGB color space. If I understood it right, it will allow me to see a wider range of colors since the Adobe RGB color space is Greater than the sRGB color space.

Obviously the image must be converted to the proper colorspace. But, how will the monitor behave in the entire rest of the OS? The os is designed to work with normal monitors, do i have to tell the system somehow that I want to use the monitor in Adobe RGB color space? i noticed that if I enable Adobe RGB on the monitor some colors look crazy.. In particular the reds look over saturated. 
If i open a normal sRGB jpg in the Windows photo viewer, will the colors be correct or will they be messed up due to the monitor profile? what is the PROPER procedure to work with an adobe RGB monitor in Windows?

Comment: I think that Windows is a bad environment for wide gamut displays. It leaves the gamut mapping to individual applications, and most of them don't do it. Photoshop obviously does, and maybe even some Microsoft apps such as their photo viewer - I don't know. I find it odd that you notice the difference most in the reds, since the red point of Adobe RGB is close to sRGB.

Comment: might be because i am a programmer, and my working environment is mainly gray with red buttons.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your monitor covers the AdobeRGB gamut then it does that all the time usually. There are some high end monitors (BENQ and EIZO come to mind) that have modes for the sole purpose of quickly previewing things as though you're a "normal user" with a cheap monitor. But it has absolutely nothing to do with Adobe software suite.

Your Greens will be the most noticeable because of how vision works combined with your now enhanced gamut:

[image]

But, the image didn't get more Green or Red or anything else. It was always that way. You just couldn't see it before. If you went to do a high quality print though those colors already existed. Now you can see them on your monitor to make the correct adjustments.

Comment: thanks, but is it enough to simply connect the monitor and enable "adobe rgb" in the settings of the monitor, or do i have to tell Windows that i am using adobe rgb profile on my monitor?

Comment: @sharkyenergy it has nothing to do with Windows. Plug it in, hopefully calibrate it, and your set.

Comment: yes, i do calibrate it. What I am trying to say is that on a normal mointor 255,0,0 produces a specific red. on a wide gamut, the same value produces a "redder" red. If I get an error message in Windows, and it has a red icon, will this red be as red as on a normal monitor, (read, how it is designed to be displayed) or will it be the fully saturated red of the adobe rgb color space? what I am trying to understand is if Windows has ha setting to compensate and display everything that is not inside a color managed program correctly. difficult to explain, hope you understand.

Comment: see this: http://superuser.com/questions/164793/how-can-i-reduce-saturation-on-my-wide-gamut-monitor-to-have-it-display-at-srgb

Comment: @sharkyenergy It will be the brighter more saturated red. It was ALWAYS the brighter more saturated red. Whether John Doe on his HP Desktop or Jane Doe on her Galaxy Tab can see the brighter red or not doesn't change that it is, and always was, the brighter red.

Comment: so it would be better to stay in sRGB on normal use, and then switch to adobe RGB when in Photoshop? (can be turned on and off)

Comment: @sharkyenergy that's up to you really. I think this article might help you: http://davidjohnstone.net/blog/2013/06/be-careful-when-buying-a-wide-gamut-monitor